# How to check multiples fotos if is null

Tags: php, laravel

Good night !

I am creating a validation for multiples files for Laravel5. I have this code in PHP who it works if I send an image

```
  public function uploadFotos(UploadFotosRequest $request){
      $image = $request->file('photo');

      $identificador = \Request::input('id');
      $pi=PI::find($identificador );
        foreach($image as $file){
              $fotosPI= new PhotosPI();
              $fotosPI->ruta = 'images/punto_interes/'.$pi->id.'/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
              $file->move('images/pi/'.$pi->id.'/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
              $fotosPI->creador_id=Auth::user()->id;
              $fotosPI->punto_interes_id=$puntoInteres->id;
              $fotosPI->save();
        } 

    }
```

The Request validation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UploadFotosRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'photo' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

When I don't send any images I recieve the following error and I need to control if photo receive an image or not.

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object
```

Comment: What's inside $image? Can you debug it using XDebug or print_r/var_dump?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> NULL }   I receive an array , I need to check this @Willian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove false values (after casting) with [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$image = array_filter($request->file('photo'));
```